# I need to get the text from uma file and put into another empty file

Tags: python-3.x, string, text

this is the code i made till now, i need a help to solve this problem, i am trying to get the text from one file and put it in another file but i didn t fin a way to do this correctly.
When i run this code my file is empty.

```
f = open('teste.txt','r')
texto = f.readlines()

x = 0

while x < len(texto):
    if texto[x] == "\n":
        local = texto.index(texto[x])
        texto.pop(local)
    else:
        texto[x] = texto[x].split(',')
        x += 1
    # print(texto[1])


texto1 = open('gravando.txt','r+')
#   texto1.write(texto[1,5,6,7,8])
(texto1.write(line) for line in (texto[i] for i in [1,5,6,7,8]))

print('O conteudo do texto1 e ', texto1.readlines())
```

This is the text in file teste.txt

Name:       compute-resources
Namespace:  voting-application
Scopes:     NotTerminating
 * Matches all pods that do not have an active deadline. These pods usually include long running pods whose container command is not expected to terminate.
Resource       Used  Hard
--------       ----  ----
limits.cpu     4     4
limits.memory  2Gi   2Gi

And this is the result i expected

Namespace:  voting-application
Resource       Used  Hard
--------       ----  ----
limits.cpu     4     4
limits.memory  2Gi   2Gi

Comment: Well, for starters `(texto1.write(line) for line in (texto[i] for i in [1,5,6,7,8]))` is creating generator, the loops there aren't executed in your code. What is your input file and what is the expected output? Can you edit your question and put the data there?

Comment: I will put here the text, but the idea is just to get part of the text of the first file and write it in the secondo file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, You are trying to copy one text from file to another by omitting some lines such as new lines. Also, only trying to write only certain lines like 1,5,6

Below is correction while writing in another file,

```
f = open('teste.txt','r')
texto = f.readlines()

x = 0

while x < len(texto):
    if texto[x] == "\n":
        local = texto.index(texto[x])
        texto.pop(local)
    else:        
        x += 1
    # print(texto[1])
texto1 = open('gravando.txt','r+')
[texto1.write(texto[i]) for i in [1,5,6,7,8]]
```

or you can do like this,

```
for i in [1,5,6,7,8]:
    texto1.write(texto[i])
```

I would suggest file handling operation should be performed using context manager,

```
with open("test.txt", "w") as f:    
    [f.write(texto[i]) for i in [1,5,6,7,8]]
```

Comment: I got an error, it didn t allowed to put the list there
File "c:\Users\Eric Vitta\Documents\python\openshift\parseQuota.py", line 20, in <listcomp>
    [texto1.write(texto[i]) for i in [1,5,6,7,8]] 
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list

Comment: Why are you doing split of comma? do you require only selected part after split?

Comment: This only happen if the first condition isn t true

Comment: Yes. Why splitting the line on comma? So If you don't want just directly assign without splitting , or simple remove it. Do you want commas in line in final output?

Comment: If you just want to remove the , you can update last line as `[texto1.write("".join(texto[i])) for i in [1,5,6,7,8]]`

Comment: There are no problems with the commas, it is just a way to split the text.
And i only need to aplit the text in lines , put them inside a list and in the end write the lines that i need  in another file

Comment: It worked as i needed , thanks a lot for your help and pacience